# How to highlight (colorize) the syntax of configuration files (like .ini or .conf)?

Tags: syntax, highlighting

I need to highlight the syntax of files containing lines with parameters and their values in LaTeX. Let's say I have a following file:

```
# some comment
parameter1 = value of parameter1
parameter2 = some another value
# and so on ...
```

Is it possible to colorize it with 3 colors: one for comments, one for parameter names and one for their values?

Comment: Are you using the [`listings`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) package?

Comment: I know this package, but I don't know if I can use it in such purpose and even whether it's possible.

Comment: check `lstdefinelanguage` command in the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package manual.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a ConTeXt solution, in case someone is interested. The [vim](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md) module uses the  vim editor to provide syntax highlighting, which has support for a huge number of languages, so there is no need to create your own parsing style.

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[INI][syntax=dosini]


\starttext
\startINI
# some comment
parameter1 = value of parameter1
parameter2 = some another value
# and so on ...
\stopINI
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The vim module automatically caches the result, so there is no considerable performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you a starting point I made the following MWE to show the possibilities of package `listings`. The first example shows how to use an existing language in package `listings`, the second example shows how you can define a new language `username` to be used with package `listings` for highlighting the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor,showframe}

\lstdefinestyle{ConfigFiles}{% define own style
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  linewidth=0.9\linewidth,
  breaklines=true,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
  commentstyle=\color{cyan},
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
  tabsize=2,
  morekeywords = {parameter},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{username}{% new language for listings
  morekeywords={parameter1,parameter2,wert},
  sensitive=false,
  morecomment=[l]{\#},      % comment
  morestring=[b]",          % string def
}

\begin{document}

First example with \texttt{lstlisting} and language \LaTeX:

\begin{lstlisting}[style=ConfigFiles]
% File name.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{ConfigFiles}{
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},       % comment
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},   % comment
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  tabsize=2,
  parameter=wert,
  morekeywords = {parameter},
}
\begin{document}               % comment
Text "text" text               % comment
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

Second example with new language \texttt{username}:

\begin{lstlisting}[language={username},keywordstyle=\color{blue},stringstyle=\color{green}]
# some comment
parameter1 = value of parameter1
parameter2 = some another value
parameter3 = wert
# and so on "and so on" ...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```