# Highlighting for viml in latex?

Tags: vim, highlighting

I want syntax highlighting for vim scripts in my latex document. So if I write

```
\begin{lstlisting}
autocmd FileType c setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
\end{lstlisting}
```

it should highlight this viml source.

I googled around but did not get any good result, as google does not understand what I want. So maybe it is my fault because I don't know how to use google, or it is googles fault because it is not able to understand me.  Are there any packages/settings/foobar which help me to do this?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8569853/1076493) could help you out?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72837/how-to-highlight-colorize-the-syntax-of-configuration-files-like-ini-or-con).

Answer (score 1):

Since vim scripts are not one of the the languages supported with a built-in analyzer in the listings package, you will have to:

1. Write an analyzer for listings,
2. Substitute another analyzer and tweak keywords (might the sh analyzer be adequate?),
3. Find a highlighter that will substitute in Latex.  Minted/ Pygments doesn't support vim scripts, but it might be easier to write your own support, or
4. Switch to Context: Context's Vim module supports vim scripts; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73109/175

For the fourth choice, in Context you might enter:

```
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping[VIM][syntax=vim]

\starttext
\startVIM
  autocmd FileType c setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
\stopVIM
\stoptext
```

Comment: I made a minor improvement in the context code. I hope that you do not mind.