# Listings style for INI (conf) files

Tags: listings, color

I'm trying to create a simple style for Windows INI files using the listings package

I'd like this results:

- purple [sections] tags
- red assignment operators (= and :)
- gray comment lines starting with (; or #)

Here is how Notepad++ highlights it.

[image: Windows INI highlight]

I tried to adapt code from [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73105/65606) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101135/65606).

So far I was able to achieve purple [tags] and ; comments. But I can't get the assignment operators to hightlight, nor the # comments to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Ini}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    columns=fullflexible,
    tag=[s]{[]},
    tagstyle=\color{Orchid}\bfseries,
    usekeywordsintag=true,
    morecomment=[l]{;},
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
    alsoletter={=},
    ndkeywords={=},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{green}\bfseries
}[html]

\title{INI test}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   INI file highlighting test.

    \begin{lstlisting}[language={Ini}]
    ; comment1
    [section1]
    var1 = val1
    var2 = val2

    #comment2
    [section2]
    var1: val1
    var2: val2
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What kind of `.ini` files do you mean? Windows or `KDE` like settings? Can you provide a working tex code with an example `.ini`?

Comment: I added an example and highlight from Notepad++ (similar in function, but different colors).

Comment: You should use `otherkeywords` for symbols instead of (the deprecated) ndkeywords (I'll show you how in an answer)

Comment: I think you're abusing the `tag` and `tagstyle` keys, here. You should use `moredelim`, instead. You also need to add `morecomment=[l]{\#}`.

Comment: @Jubobs I tried, but it doesn't work. I suspect building on the html style is creating problems for the assignment operators, but I can't get the tags to work like that.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs Fixed that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to implement this is avoiding using the `html` style as a base:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Ini}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    columns=fullflexible,
    morecomment=[s][\color{Orchid}\bfseries]{[}{]},
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    morecomment=[l]{;},
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
    morekeywords={},
    otherkeywords={=,:},
    keywordstyle={\color{green}\bfseries}
}
```

This satisfies the requirements but will not highlight html inside the ini's values.

Your problem was:

- `#` cannot be specified as a comment delimiter without escaping it (it is a special character)
- to highlight symbols instead of changing their class it is better to use `otherkeywords` (which can only be used if `morekeywords` is used first, hence the `morekeywords={}` entry)
- you were abusing `tags` where `morecomment` is more than sufficient (you could also have used `moredelim`)

Comment: Good approach. +1

Comment: Thank you. Now there's a simple and effective configuration for INI files around here. +1 if you think the question was worthy as well ;)